# Why my checkbox does not come out? I use react, typescript and next.Js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

I don't understand why my Checkbox does not unchecked out when I want click it a second time. I can checked but not unchecked... I use typescript react and next.js.
Some One could help me please?
The first part is when I call the handle and the second part is when I use my form.

I had to descibe all my state a first time in a block state and a second time in a constructor.

```
export interface IdFormBlockProps {
  
  }

  export interface IdFormBlockState{
    user: string;
    email: string;
    enterprise: string;
    tel: number;
    speakProject: string;
    checked1: boolean;
    checked2: boolean;
    checked3: boolean;
    checked4: boolean;
    budget: string ;
    budgets: string[];
    knowledge: string;
    knowledges: string[];
    contactEmail: string;
    contactTel: string;
  
  }
export default class Form extends React.Component <IdFormBlockProps, IdFormBlockState>{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      user :"",
      email : "",
      enterprise : "",
      tel : null,
      speakProject: "",
      checked1: false,
      checked2: false,
      checked3: false,
      checked4: false,
      budget: "",
      budgets: ["Sélectionnez par tranche", "< 1000€", "< 2000€", "< 3000€", " > 3000€"],  // I give the value for the budget form 
      knowledge: "",
      knowledges: ["Sélectionnez", "Facebook", "Instagram", "linkedIn", "un moteur de recherche"],    // I give the value for the knowledge form
      contactEmail: "",
      contactTel: "",
    }
    this.handleCheckboxChange = this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this);
    this.handleContacting = this.handleContacting.bind(this);
    this.handleKnowledge = this.handleKnowledge.bind(this);
    this.handleProject = this.handleProject.bind(this);
    this.handleBudget = this.handleBudget.bind(this);
    this.handleUser = this.handleUser.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

  };
  handleCheckboxChange = (event, index) => {
    let key = "checked"+index;
    this.setState({[key]:event.target.value} as IdFormBlockState )
    console.log(event.target)
  }
```

```
  {/* .............this is the block where the user says what he needs.................................. */}
              <div className="checkboxNeeds">
                <fieldset>
                  <legend className="yourNeed">De quoi avez-vous besoin ?</legend>
                  <div className="newProject">
                    <label htmlFor="newproject">Je souhaite lancer un nouveau projet !</label>
                    <input 
                      type="checkbox" 
                      id="newProject" 
                      name="yourNeed[]"
                      checked={this.state.checked1}
                      onChange={(event) => this.handleCheckboxChange(event, 1)}/>
                  </div>

                  <div className="boostActivity">
                    <label htmlFor="boostActivity">Je souhaite booster mon activité !</label>
                    <input 
                      type="checkbox" 
                      id="boostActivity" 
                      name="yourNeed[]"
                      checked={this.state.checked2}
                      onChange={(event) => this.handleCheckboxChange(event, 2)}/>
                  </div>

                  <div className="content">
                    <label htmlFor="content">Je souhaite alimenter mon contenu</label>
                    <input 
                      type="checkbox" 
                      id="content" 
                      name="yourNeed[]"
                      checked={this.state.checked3}
                      onChange={(event) => this.handleCheckboxChange(event, 3)}/>
                  </div>

                  <div className="content2">
                    <label htmlFor="content2">Je souhaite alimenter mon contenu, encore...</label>
                    <input 
                      type="checkbox" 
                      id="content2" 
                      name="yourNeed[]"
                      checked={this.state.checked4}
                      onChange={(event) => this.handleCheckboxChange(event, 4)}/>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event.target.checked instead of value.

This is a boolean unlike the value, which you do not set and becomes a string.

here's a working simple example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-dan-m9wxb

```
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        onClick={(e) => setChecked(e.target.checked)}
      />
```